# Camel - No component found with scheme:mybatis

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, mybatis

I've got a Spring Boot app that makes use of Camel and Mybatis. I've got the following mybatis dependencies in pom.xml:

**pom.xml**

```
....
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-mybatis</artifactId>
    <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
....
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
....
```

I've got the following route:

**MyRoute.java**

```
@Component
public class MyRoute extends SpringRouteBuilder{

    @Autowired
    MQConnectionProperties mqConnectionProperties;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from(mqConnectionProperties.getResponseQueue())
        .to("mybatis:selectLogByPrimaryKey?statementType=SelectOne")
        .process(new TargetSystemProcessor())
        .end()
    }
}
```

and the test for the route:

**MyRouteUnitTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyRouteTestConfiguration.class})
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class MyRouteUnitTest extends CamelTestSupport{

    @Mock
    MyBatisComponent mybatis;
    @Autowired
    MQConnectionProperties mqProps;
    @Autowired
    MyRouteBuilder route;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        context.addComponent("mybatis", mybatis);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        startCamelContext();

        assertTrue(true);

        stopCamelContext();
    }
}
```

When I try to start the test without adding mybatis as a component to the context, I get this error:

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route My_Route at: >>> To[mybatis:selectAuditLogByPrimaryKey?statementType=SelectOne] <<< in route: Route(My_Route)[[From[seda:inpu... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: mybatis://selectAuditLogByPrimaryKey?statementType=SelectOne due to: Cannot auto create component: mybatis
....
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: mybatis://selectAuditLogByPrimaryKey?statementType=SelectOne due to: Cannot auto create component: mybatis
....
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Cannot find resource: SqlMapConfig.xml in classpath for URI: SqlMapConfig.xml
```

Whenever I add the component to the context as shown i nthe test above, I get this error:

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route My_Route at: >>> To[mybatis:selectAuditLogByPrimaryKey?statementType=SelectOne] <<< in route: Route(My_Route)[[From[seda:inpu... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: mybatis://selectAuditLogByPrimaryKey?statementType=SelectOne due to: No component found with scheme: mybatis
```

As far as I can tell, I've got the right dependencies i nthe pom file to hook all of this together, and mybatis works fine in the source code. For unit testing I can work around it by replacing the endpoint, but I can't write any integration tests for my route

Comment: Well, it kind of says that `Cannot find resource: SqlMapConfig.xml in classpath for URI: SqlMapConfig.xml`, so I'd check my configuration to see if one (either the real or test specific) it's available during the test phase.

Comment: There isn't one in the project, presumably because of the spring boot mybatis starter, so im not entirely certain how its hooked up

Comment: It's possible, I haven't used neither spring nor camel mybatis so far. Nonetheless putting together the [camel docs](http://camel.apache.org/mybatis.html) (scroll to the end and look for `ref="sqlSessionFactory"`) and the [mybatis spring boot starter docs](http://www.mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/) it looks like you should be able to configure camel to use the auto-registered instance of `SqlSessionFactoryBean`. Just make sure the test context includes all the bean definitions

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look through those, thanks